# Handling concurrency issues on multithreaded service

Tags: multithreading, wcf, concurrency, locking, deadlock

I am designing a web service(wcf) that has some of the static dictionaries (ie. maintaining some states of the server and connected clients). The service is in single instance mode and multiple concurrency, as shown below.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]   
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorConcurrency   
{   
    ...  
}
```

There are various operations that reads and writes to this static variables. I have one class level lock object and the way I am trying to avoid locks is using that object whenever any operations try to access that particular static variables.

Did I handling the concurrency correctly, as shown below? There can be various instances of the client accessing the service, i.e.

- Client1 using the service to modify() dictionary
- Client2 using the service to clear() dictionary
- Client3 using the service to read() dictionary

The sample code looks like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorConcurrency
    {   
        private static int clientId;
        private static object lockObject = new object();
        private static Dictionary<int, Number> numberList = new Dictionary<int, Number>();


    public static Number ReadNumber(int n)
    {
        Number info;
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (!numberList.TryGetValue(n, out info))
            ...
        }
    }

    public static bool Modify(Number number)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public bool Clear()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            numberList.Clear();
            ...
        }               
    }
}
```

Is my code thread safe? Or, moreover Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Did you run it ? What happened ?

Comment: @jsanalytics Its running as expected, but I am not confident as if this will be sufficient enough to address possible deadlocks or not? Also, Is it difference if I use different lock objects for each method as I didn't notice any changes in the result?

Comment: Did you run a scenario with multiple tasks making multiple calls to your service at the same time?

Comment: @jsanalytics I am not too familiar with how to debug these concurrency issues from real services, so hope you could provide some insights which I would highly appreciate. For my tests, I invoked the same services from different test apps: console application and desktop application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using just one resource (i.e `lockObject`) deadlocks are impossible. To get a deadlock you need to have at least two resources.

> Is my code thread safe?

If you are using `Dictionary<,>` to avoid any concurrency problems every interaction with that dictionary should be wrapped by `lock(lockObject){}` as you did. So, you code is thread safe.

> Am I doing it correctly?

You are doing correctly but if you are using `.Net 4` or newest you have more convenient option with thread safe [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2). It was designed special for cases like your. The difference is in that you can forget about `lock` blocks. It will not throw an exception when one caller iterates through the dictionary and the second caller changes the dictionary. `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements the `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` and in addition, provides convenient methods like `TryAdd`, `TryUpdate` and other.

So, you definitely need to you use `ConcurrentDictionary` if it is possible, since it makes code more cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and additional insights. I will explore the Concurrent Types